# Asp.net MVC - error after second attempt on opening a modal window

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to implement bootstrap modal window when opening details. The modal window is open on ajax call. The problem is, I can only open it once. It opens with whole template, while it should not and during the second attempt I get error:

> Uncaught error: modal is not a function

Then I get this error and can not open modal window any more.

Container for main view:

```
<div id="data-container">
    @Html.Action("PartialDisplay", "Disp")
</div>
```

I display all data in partial view, so the controller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Display()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public PartialViewResult PartialDisplay(int[] checkId)
        {
            if (checkId == null)
            {
               [my code]
                return PartialView(viewModel);
            }
```

details view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PartialDisplay";
    Layout = null;
}

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Detail</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalContent">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nazev Jidla</th>
            <th>Kategorie</th>
            <th>Akce</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Jidlo jidlo in Model.Jidlos)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => jidlo.name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => jidlo.Category.popis)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }) |
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Details","Details", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }, new AjaxOptions(){ UpdateTargetId = "modalContent", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnBegin = "openModalWindow" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = jidlo.JidloID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('opravdu smazat polozku " + jidlo.name + "?');" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModalWindow() {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }
</script>
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Jidlo jidlo = db.Jidlos.Find(id);
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView(jidlo);
            }
            else {
            return View(jidlo);
            }
        }
```

Layout scripts included:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
```

What am I missing here? I tried to change priority for loading and couple more things like add jQuery.noConflict to script and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is loading jquery script twice

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")"></script>
```

That is correct.

Another this was removing the template markup in the details view.